# How to pass a parameter that contains the XML request in php?

Tags: php, xml, soap

I'm trying to convert a Cardinal XML API request to PHP so I can send the request over the web. Unfortunately no success as it gives me the following error:

> 2010 Invalid Request Format: Empty Request

I do think I'm reaching the server but there's something wrong with my PHP request.

This is my PHP code:

```
$soapUrl = "https://centineltest.cardinalcommerce.com/maps/txns.asp";

$xml_post_string = 
"<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance' xmlns:xsd='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema' xmlns:soap='http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope'>

<soap:Body>

'cmpi_msg='

<CardinalMPI>
    <MsgType>cmpi_lookup</MsgType>
    <Version>1.7</Version>

    <ProcessorId>252-01</ProcessorId>
    <MerchantId>IVRTest</MerchantId>
    <TransactionPwd>2h7mg3xN9JLQgQ</TransactionPwd>
    <TransactionType>C</TransactionType>

    <OrderNumber>CMY_IVR_Test1</OrderNumber>

    <Amount>100</Amount>
    <CurrencyCode>356</CurrencyCode>

    <CardNumber>4000000000000002</CardNumber>
    <CardExpMonth>05</CardExpMonth>
    <CardExpYear>2020</CardExpYear>

    <BillingFirstName>John</BillingFirstName>
    <BillingLastName>Doe</BillingLastName>
    <BillingAddress1>The Capital, C-70, G-Block</BillingAddress1>
    <BillingAddress2/>
    <BillingPhone>555-8675-309</BillingPhone>
    <BillingCity>Mumbai</BillingCity>
    <BillingState></BillingState>
    <BillingPostalCode>400051</BillingPostalCode>
    <BillingCountryCode>IN</BillingCountryCode>

    <MessageCategory>01</MessageCategory>
    <CategoryCode>01</CategoryCode>

    <IPAddress>127.0.0.1</IPAddress>
    <UserAgent>Jakarta Commons-HttpClient/3.1</UserAgent>

    <Item_Name_1>iPod</Item_Name_1>
    <Item_Desc_1>Apple iPod</Item_Desc_1>
    <Item_Price_1>10000</Item_Price_1>
    <Item_Quantity_1>1</Item_Quantity_1>
    <Item_SKU_1>8675309</Item_SKU_1>

    <DeviceChannel>browser</DeviceChannel>
    <BrowserColorDepth>500</BrowserColorDepth>
    <BrowserHeader>text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,</BrowserHeader>
    <BrowserJavaEnabled>true</BrowserJavaEnabled>
    <BrowserLanguage>English</BrowserLanguage>
    <BrowserScreenHeight>980</BrowserScreenHeight>
    <BrowserScreenWidth>1080</BrowserScreenWidth>
    <BrowserTimeZone>-1:00</BrowserTimeZone>

    <AuthenticationChannel>IVR</AuthenticationChannel>
    <MobileIdFormat>I</MobileIdFormat>
    <MobileId/>
    <PareqChannel>Direct value</PareqChannel>
    <ShoppingChannel>IVR</ShoppingChannel>
    <TtpCredential/>

</CardinalMPI>

</soap:Body>

</soap:Envelope>";

$headers = array(
"POST /package/package_1.3/packageservices.asmx HTTP/1.1",
"Host: cybersource.cardinalcommerce.com",
"Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
"Content-Length: ".strlen($xml_post_string)
); 

$url = $soapUrl;

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $xml_post_string);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST,  2);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);

$response = curl_exec($ch); 
curl_close($ch);

$response1 = str_replace("<soap:Body>","",$response);
$response2 = str_replace("</soap:Body>","",$response1);

$parser = simplexml_load_string($response2);

?>
```

I'm lost on how to code the parameter cmpi_msg, as it's the first time I saw an XML request inside a parameter. But to post a request to Centinel, I need the message to be passed www-form-urlencoded in the parameter cmpi_msg.

When I use POSTMAN and send the same request like below, I'm able to get a successful response.

```
cmpi_msg='<CardinalMPI>
    <MsgType>cmpi_lookup</MsgType>
    <Version>1.7</Version>

     <ProcessorId>252-01</ProcessorId>
    <MerchantId>IVRTest</MerchantId>
    <TransactionPwd>2h7mg3xN9JLQgQ</TransactionPwd>
    <TransactionType>C</TransactionType>

    <OrderNumber>CMY_IVR_Test1</OrderNumber>

    <Amount>100</Amount>
    <CurrencyCode>356</CurrencyCode>

    <CardNumber>4000000000000002</CardNumber>
    <CardExpMonth>05</CardExpMonth>
    <CardExpYear>2020</CardExpYear>

    <BillingFirstName>John</BillingFirstName>
    <BillingLastName>Doe</BillingLastName>
    <BillingAddress1>The Capital, C-70, G-Block</BillingAddress1>
    <BillingAddress2/>
    <BillingPhone>555-8675-309</BillingPhone>
    <BillingCity>Mumbai</BillingCity>
    <BillingState></BillingState>
    <BillingPostalCode>400051</BillingPostalCode>
    <BillingCountryCode>IN</BillingCountryCode>

    <MessageCategory>01</MessageCategory>
    <CategoryCode>01</CategoryCode>

    <IPAddress>127.0.0.1</IPAddress>
    <UserAgent>Jakarta Commons-HttpClient/3.1</UserAgent>

    <Item_Name_1>iPod</Item_Name_1>
    <Item_Desc_1>Apple iPod</Item_Desc_1>
    <Item_Price_1>10000</Item_Price_1>
    <Item_Quantity_1>1</Item_Quantity_1>
    <Item_SKU_1>8675309</Item_SKU_1>

    <DeviceChannel>browser</DeviceChannel>
    <BrowserColorDepth>500</BrowserColorDepth>
    <BrowserHeader>text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,</BrowserHeader>
    <BrowserJavaEnabled>true</BrowserJavaEnabled>
    <BrowserLanguage>English</BrowserLanguage>
    <BrowserScreenHeight>980</BrowserScreenHeight>
    <BrowserScreenWidth>1080</BrowserScreenWidth>
    <BrowserTimeZone>-1:00</BrowserTimeZone>

    <AuthenticationChannel>IVR</AuthenticationChannel>
    <MobileIdFormat>I</MobileIdFormat>
    <MobileId/>
    <PareqChannel>Direct value</PareqChannel>
    <ShoppingChannel>IVR</ShoppingChannel>
    <TtpCredential/>

</CardinalMPI>'
```

So I think my only error has something to do on how to specify the cmpi_msg parameter. Hope you can help out! Thanks in advance!

Comment: `'cmpi_msg='` looks dubious in the position it is

Comment: Also- the API endpoint is `https` so you should have additional options set for the curl request to deal with an SSL connection

Comment: Oh thanks for pointing that out! Got that one! 
For the cmpi_msg, I already tried different ways to specify it, but no luck.

Comment: Is there a link you can share for the documentation?

Comment: This is the guide but it's not really helpful as you need to make your own API call based on the fields needs to be passed and no sample at all.
https://cardinaldocs.atlassian.net/wiki/spaces/CCen/pages/905478187/Lookup+Request+Response